# jquery mobile loader not showing in chrome, emulator and android mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating jquery mobile app using phonegap, When i fire ajax request i am showing ajax loading spinner, which is working fine in Firefox but it doesn't come up with chrome, emulator and real android mobile device.

Below is the code that i am using

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#agenda2",function(){
$.mobile.loading('show', {
    text: 'Please wait',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'a',
    html: ""
});
// Code for ajax request goes here 
});
```

Comment: try `$('.ui-loader').show();` if it doesn't show, check your DOM for a div with class `ui-loader`. What version are you using?

Comment: That also doesnt work, I tried to monitor it will firebug and noticed that it start spinning when ajax request completes, I even tried to show spinner immediately as soon as user clicks on element but still it shows up when request completes.

Comment: maybe _Access-Control-Allow-Origin_ problem? since it occurs with chrome?

Comment: I am working on localhost only, and php that i am accessing is within the same directory, and it returns results so thats not the problem i think.